# Associative array output in html table

Tags: php

I have obtained an array output from a curl command. Now, I need to place that output in a table. I have written the entire code in php. 
The .phtml part is:

```
echo "<table border='1'>


<tr><td>NAME</td></tr>
                <tr><td>COUNTRY</td></tr>
                </table>";
```

The loop part is:

```
foreach($arr['fruits'] as $key=>$fruit) {
                ?>
             <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->NAME["Name"];}?></td></tr>
             <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->COUNTRY["Country"];}?></td></tr>
```

I'm very very new to all this. So, I don't really know what I'm exactly doing. Thanks in advance...

Comment: where is the question? any errors?

Comment: So `$arr` is an array of objects, with properties that are associative arrays?

Comment: yea, I get parse errors

Comment: yes, its an array of objects

Comment: Why you used } in each td tag ?

Comment: I want to put the content of the associative array in html table

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this :

Considering your array structure is like this :

```
$your_array   = array(array("name"=>"prasanth","country"=>"India"),
                      array("name"=>"bendra","country"=>"India"),
                      array("name"=>"User","country"=>"US")
                     );

<?php foreach($your_array as $key=>$fruit) { ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $fruit['name'];?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo $fruit['country'];?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, I get error that "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 0):

Here's all code.

```
<?php
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><td>NAME</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>COUNTRY</td></tr>";
        foreach($arr['fruits'] as $key=>$fruit) {
                        ?>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->NAME["Name"];?></td></tr>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->COUNTRY["Country"];?></td></tr>
        <?php ;}
    echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Well, I get error that  "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: what function do you use for fetching result? `_fetch_assoc()` or `_fetch_method` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this sort of thing:

```
$fruit->NAME["Name"]
```

This means in the `$fruit` object look for a property called `NAME` that is an array containing the key `"Name"`.

Also, your table isn't very tabular with only one cell per row.  I would try something like this (if `$fruit` is really an array not an object):

```
<table border="1">
   <tr><th>Name</th><th>Country</th></tr>
<?php
foreach( $arr['fruits'] as $fruit ) {
   echo "<tr><td>$fruit['NAME']</td><td>$fruit['COUNTRY']</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

We can't help you without knowing the actual structure of `$arr['fruits']`